# Regular expression find and replace in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a table that contains a number of rows with columns containing a URL. The URL is of the form:

`http://one.example1.com:9999/dotFile.com`

I would like to replace all matches in that column with `http://example2.com/dotFile.com` while retaining everything after :9999. I have found some documentation on regexp_matches and regexp_replace, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

if you know the url, you don't have to use regex. replace() function should work for you:

```
replace(string text, from text, to text)        
Replace all occurrences in string of substring from with substring to   
example: replace('abcdefabcdef', 'cd', 'XX')    abXXefabXXef
```

you could try:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET
  yourcolumn = replace(yourcolumn, 'one.example1.com:9999','example2.com')
;
```

Comment: Thanks , that did the trick.
update table
SET field =
replace(field, 'one.example1.com:9999','example2.com')

Comment: This comment is what the answer is missing

Answer (score 76):

To replace a fixed string, use the simple `replace()` function.

To replace a dynamic string, you can use `regexp_replace()` like this:

```
UPDATE
  YourTable
SET
  TheColumn = regexp_replace(
    TheColumn, 'http://[^:\s]+:9999(\S+)', 'http://example2.com\1', 'g'
  )
```

Comment: `replace()` does a simpler job here, as already you commented yourself. However, to replace "all matches" with `regexp_replace()`, you have to add the 4th parameter `'g'` .. for "globally".

Comment: @Erwin Thanks for the hint. I've included that.

Comment: I was looking for one I can use in a where clause like ` UPDATE ... WHERE  "email" = regexp_matches("email", E'.[co.tz]')` so to filter and improve the update speed. But this is alright too, since I'm only doing this once, in developement. Thank you, for I really wanted a `regexp` solution tho. :)

Comment: If no part of your search string is variable, using regex is pointless. Since regex are much slower than basic string searches I would try to avoid them whereever possible. A "last 5 characters of the column = 'co.tz'" type of search will be faster than the regex equivalent.